# Rails 4 fragment caching with stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, memcached, sprockets

Rails 4 uses cache_digests (https://github.com/rails/cache_digests) to assist with fragment cache invalidation: cache_digests creates an MD5 hash of a template and all its known dependencies, allowing fragment caches to become invalidated by assigning a new key when a template or its dependency changes.

My question is: will a fragment cache wrapping `stylesheet_link_tag` get invalidated if the application.css file's MD5 hash changes during `rake assets:precompile`? Right now do this in our header:

```
<% cache("header-cache-key") do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<% end %>
```

Is this safe? My fear is that when the CSS or JS changes, `application-xxxxxxx.css` will become `application-yyyyyyy.css`, but our header will be cached with the old `application-xxxxxxx.css`. Then if `application-xxxxxxx.css` is gone from `public/assets`, this will result in an ugly page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the cache wont be busted/invalidated on changes to compiled CSS/JS.

The way Rails busts the cache on a code change is done by inserting a file's hash into the view's cache key.

E.g say you have a view file at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Rails generates a hash from the file's content (i.e the HTML/Ruby code, not the executed output). Let's pretend the hash generated is 'abdefg123'.

If `application.html.erb` has the following cache code:

```
<% cache("header-cache-key") do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<% end %>
```

The actual cache key generated is something along the of lines `"views/layouts/application-abcdefg123/header-cache-key"`.

As a change in the compiled CSS/JS doesn't actually change the Ruby/HTML in the file, the computed hash for the layout code doesn't change and therefore the cache key for 'header-cache-key' is the same, meaning the cache isn't busted.